# How to dispose of diesel

Tags: hhr

My daughter-in-law a diesel to my gas tank and weecycled it out now how do I properly dispose of the diesel that was removed?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

Your local council run recycling site, if you have one, should take it.

If not, find someone who owns an older, more agricultural, diesel engined vehicle, e.g. a tractor or older Land Rover. They may well be able to make use of it by mixing it with fresh Diesel (to dilute the petrol that's contaminated it) and burning it.

Comment: Here in the States, many garages use oil burners (burns waste engine oil from automobiles) to heat their shops in the winter time. Diesel can be added to these without issue. A gallon or two of it will actually go a long way.